# in Xcode which IBAction is responsible for detecting the release of a button

Tags: xcode, image, uibutton, uiimage, ibaction

i have set an image for a UIBUTTON. When this button is clicked a highlighted version of the Image is shown. When the user releases the button, this highlighted image should go back to hidden state, through "BUTTON.hidden = YES" .. The problem is I don't know which IBAction listens for release of a button. I have tried a number of them but no success.

I am using "touch down" to detect the touch.

Answer (score 1):

<strike>Try [UIControlEventTouchUpInside](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIControl_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006779-RH2-SW3).</strike>

**Edit:**
To see what control states you can react to, see [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIControl_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006779-RH2-SW11).
This is how to control the button image depending on the state:

```
[myButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"button_state_normal"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[myButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"button_state_selected"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
```

This way the button will return to the normal state after the user removes the finger. This does not have anything to do with IBActions.

Comment: I have used TouchUpInside to activate what the button is supposed to do. A highlighted button (my image) is displayed while the button is still being pressed. wen released this highlighted image should hide. It is this effect (hiding the image) that I'm failing to do

Comment: Ok, now I think I know what you mean. See my update answer. However, I have still now idea what you mean by `I am using "touch down" to detect the touch`. Add some code if this still does not answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIControl_Class/Reference/Reference.html

From the docs i believe

```
UIControlEventTouchUpOutside  is the event
```

**UIControlEventTouchUpOutside**

```
A touch-up event in the control where the finger is outside the bounds of the control.
Available in iOS 2.0 and later.
Declared in UIControl.h.
```

Comment: i tried using touchupoutside but the image is not going back to hidden state. the image is listed in my viewcontroller.h .. I have managed to unhide it but failing to hide it back